Definition of deducible from $D_1, \dots, D_l$ without using concept of a deduction
Kleene leave to the reader define of deducible from  $D_1, \dots, D_l$ without using the intermediate concept of a deduction in his book "Introduction to Metamathematics".
Original definition is next:
Given a list $D_1, \dots, D_l$ $(l \geq 0)$ of (occurrences of) formulas, a finite sequence of one or more (occurrences of) formulas is called a (formal) deduction from the assumption formulas $D_1, \dots, D_l$, if each formula of the sequence is either one of the formulas $D_1, \dots, D _l$, or an axiom, or an immediate consequence of preceding formulas of the sequence. A deduction is said to be a deduction of its last formula $E$; and this formula is said to be deducible from the assumption formulas (in symbols, $D_1, \dots, D_l \vdash E$).
And my attempt is next:

$\vdash E$ ($E$ is deducible)
$\{f\} \vdash E$ if $\{f\} \subset \{D\}_{i=1}^l$ (each formula of the sequence belongs to assumptions $D_1, \dots, D_l$.
$\{f\} \vdash E$ if $\{f\} \subset A$, where $A$ are axioms.
$E^\prime \vdash E$ if $\{f\} \vdash E^\prime$ (if $E^\prime$ is deducible from previous formulas).
$E$ is deducible only as required by 1-4.

Am I right?

More or less...
The author suggests to mimick the inductive def of provable of page 83.
If so, it must be:

If $E$ is an axiom, then $D_1, \ldots. D_n \vdash E$ ($E$ is deducible from...).

If $E$ is one of $D_i$, then $D_1, \ldots. D_n \vdash E$.

If $D$ is deducible form..., and $E$ is an immediate consequence of $D$, then ...

If $D$ and $F$ are deducible from... and $E$ is an immediate consequence of $D$ and $F$, then ...

A formula is deducible from... only as required by 1-4.


